# Repositioning programmatically added uibuttons on orientation change

Tags: ios, uibutton

I'm programmatically adding UIButtons to my view and I want to reposition them based on the orientation change.

I'm creating buttons by running 2 for loops for rows and cols and within the second for loop:
I'm assigning some properties and unique tags for each button. (Ex. [Best way to build 10x10 grid of UIButtons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215419/best-way-to-build-10x10-grid-of-uibuttons))

I'm detecting orientation change by listening to willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation and was hoping to call buttons by based on their tag to move them to a new position.

I need to keep the state of the buttons so I can't remove them. It has to be repositioned.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Are you simply asking how to reposition a button?  If that's the case, you can just use `[UIButton setFrame:]` and just set the coordinates to whatever makes sense in the new orientation.

Comment: The question/answer you cited are old. These days I would strongly consider using a `UICollectionView` to preform such a task. For a tutorial visit http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12

Comment: What's the question? You want to reposition the buttons when you receive `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation`? Go right ahead! What's the problem?

Comment: @matt How can I target each button with its tag. Maybe I'm having an issue with that. Thanks.

Comment: Just make sure you throw all your buttons into an array when you create your grid of buttons.  Then use that array to access each of the buttons, check their tags if need be, reposition them - whatever you need.

Comment: But yes, depending on what you're planning on doing with these buttons, a `UICollectionView` could be the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:1]; // change viewWithTag to your buttons tag number. Now you can use button to position it anyway you want.
    button.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h); // x, y, width, height
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to do this.

1) Using Autoresizing masks: Using this approach you need not do anything and the buttons automatically reposition based on the autoresizing masks set for the button with respect to its superview.

2) Second approach is to reposition the button after the rotation of the super view. You can write a method to calculate the new frame for the button based on the new width and height of its super view after rotation. There are rotation callbacks like

```
 - (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
```

3) You can also implement below method in button's superview and reset the frames of your button

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
```

Hope this helps.